# Need help with UITabBarController and orientation

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app (written using MonoTouch and currently working) that I want to add landscape orientation to.  I am using a UITabBarController.

I don't see how to create a controller that will allow me to override the "ShouldAutorotate..." method.  Can anybody point me to an example using a UITabBarController in MonoTouch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TweetStation contains a sample precisely for this setup, and propagates the rotation down all of the nested view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you subclassing UITabBarController?

You are probably non subclassing and just adding a vanilla controller in Interface Builder.  You have to subclass to override that property.

First make a new class like this:

```
//Test this, it's off the top of my head
[Register("YourTabController")]
public class YourTabController : UITabBarController
{
    public YourTabController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle) { }

    [Export("initWithCoder:")]
    public YourTabController (NSCoder coder) : base (coder) { }

    //Override should rotate
    public bool ShouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation o)
    { return true; }
}
```

Then, if you already have a UITabBarController in IB, there is a 'Class' property that you set to the name of your new class.